# How to solve error - unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to join 3 entity tables a fill-up data with few columns only from those tables into a data table

```
DataTable dttable = new DataTable();

dttable.Columns.Add("billno", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
dttable.Columns.Add("time", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("sname", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(Decimal));
dttable.Columns.Add("rate", typeof(Decimal));


var rows = from mobjbmast in Context.bmasts.AsEnumerable()
           join mobjbtran in Context.btrans
           on mobjbmast.billno equals mobjbtran.billno
           join mobjwaiter in Context.waiters
           on mobjbmast.scode equals mobjwaiter.code
           where mobjbmast.billno == mbillno
           select dttable.LoadDataRow(new object[]
           {
                 mobjbmast.billno,
                 mobjbmast.date,
                 mobjbmast.time,
                 mobjwaiter.name,
                 mobjbtran.name,
                 mobjbtran.qty,
                 mobjbtran.rate
           }, false);
```

Expected the above code to fill the data table.  But no rows yielded.  When debugged the above code, 'rows' variable shows in the debugger

> unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057'

So I tried this:

```
var rows = from mobjbmast in Context.bmasts.AsEnumerable()
           join mobjbtran in Context.btrans.AsEnumerable()
           on mobjbmast.billno equals mobjbtran.billno
           join mobjwaiter in Context.waiters.AsEnumerable()
           on mobjbmast.scode equals mobjwaiter.code
           where mobjbmast.billno == mbillno
           select new { billno = mobjbmast.billno, date = mobjbmast.date, time = mobjbmast.time, sname = mobjwaiter.name, name = mobjbtran.name, qty = mobjbtran.qty, rate = mobjbtran.rate };
```

No change in scenario.

Tried the above with `ToList()`

```
var rows = from mobjbmast in Context.bmasts.ToList()
           join mobjbtran in Context.btrans.ToList()
           on mobjbmast.billno equals mobjbtran.billno
           join mobjwaiter in Context.waiters.ToList()
           on mobjbmast.scode equals mobjwaiter.code
           where mobjbmast.billno == mbillno
           select new { billno = mobjbmast.billno, date = mobjbmast.date, time = mobjbmast.time, sname = mobjwaiter.name, name = mobjbtran.name, qty = mobjbtran.qty, rate = mobjbtran.rate };
```

This time, the error went off but in the debugger, I see 'The Enumeration yielded no results' message.

Also tried adding `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

I'm aware that I can load this output into a `List<T>`.  But here a data table is needed and a class for this is unnecessary.

How to structure the query to return a proper IEnumerable to convert into a data table?

Comment: You are using Entity and the table mapping between the database and application are not matching.  You probably updated the database and then did not update the mapping.  So you need to update the mapping and then make sure entire project gets recompiled.  Often the compiler dependencies do not recognize database changes and the object files do not get recompiled.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is not the scenario.  The database and entity tables are matching and I can tell that for sure since just above this code there are table updation codes that does the Context.SaveChanges() and after that is this code.  Hence no doubt of mis - mapping between database and entities.

Comment: Then I would make a copy of the project bin folder and delete bin.  Then recompile to force all the object modules to recompile.  Also check if both the Debug and Release executable timestamp gets built.  You may be using the Release but only building the debug.  Deleting bin folder will show these type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it like this, based on suggestions from some websites

```
DataTable dttable = new DataTable();

dttable.Columns.Add("billno", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
dttable.Columns.Add("time", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("sname", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
dttable.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(Decimal));
dttable.Columns.Add("rate", typeof(Decimal));

var rows = from mobjbmast in Context.bmasts.AsEnumerable()
           join mobjbtran in odlsContext.btrans
           on mobjbmast.billno equals mobjbtran.billno
           join mobjwaiter in Context.waiters
           on mobjbmast.scode equals mobjwaiter.code
           where mobjbmast.billno == mbillno
           let billarray = new object[]
           {
                mobjbmast.billno,
                mobjbmast.date,
                mobjbmast.time,
                mobjwaiter.name,
                mobjbtran.name,
                mobjbtran.qty,
                mobjbtran.rate
           }
           select billarray;
foreach (var array in rows)
{
    dttable.Rows.Add(array);
}
```